# How can a form be sent inside iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, post, iframe

I want to send a `form` to inside an `iframe`. How can i do this?

Comment: Please give more details - you want to submit a form that is in an iframe from the parent page or target a form to an iframe?

Comment: I edit as `send a form to iframe`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `target` attribute of form tag specifies where to open the action URL.

You can do like following :

```
<iframe name="myframe" id="frame1" src="mydetail.asp"></iframe>
<form action="../mydetail.asp" method="post" target="myframe">
<input type="submit" name="DoIt" value="DoIt">
</form>
```

The `target` attribute is used with frames to specify the frame in which the form response should be rendered. If no frame with such a name exists, the response is rendered in a new window unless overridden by the user.

Comment: why so you set the src value in the iframe ?

Answer (score 5):

Using the `target` attribute.

```
<iframe name="my_iframe" src="..."></iframe>

<form action="...." target="my_iframe">
```